# NodeJs + Angular 2 CRUD JSON parsing issue

Tags: mysql, node.js, angular, ag-grid

I have a NodeJS backend that simply does CRUD stuff.
I have this route that read a simple MySQL table

```
app.get('/fb_photo', (req, res) => {
    mysqlConnection.query('SELECT id,photo_date,photo_text from p_fb_photo_search LIMIT 10', (err, rows, fields) => {
        if (!err)
            res.send(rows);
        else
            console.log(err);
    })
});
```

If I test on the browser it produce good JSON output:

```
[{"id":23101,"photo_date":"2019-04-23T08:59:52.000Z","photo_text":"NO TEXT"},{"id":19614,"photo_date":"2018-10-20T07:46:40.000Z","photo_text":"NO TEXT"},{"id":46245,"photo_date":"2019-05-27T20:29:49.000Z","photo_text":"NO TEXT"}
```

Now in Angular frontend I have this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    title = 'app';

    columnDefs = [
        {headerName: 'id', field: 'id', sortable: true, filter: true},
        {headerName: 'photo_date', field: 'photo_date', sortable: true, filter: true},
        {headerName: 'photo_text', field: 'photo_text', sortable: true, filter: true}
    ];

    rowData: any;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.rowData = this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/fb_photo');
    }
}
```

but surprisingly the ag-grid table is failing to load and fetch record without raising any errors:
[image]

Is it there anything worng with my code? If I use AG sample JSON datasets it works.
Thx

#### EDIT

this is my app.component.html:

```
<ag-grid-angular 
style="width: 500px; height: 500px;" 
class="ag-theme-balham"
[rowData]="rowData | async"
[columnDefs]="columnDefs">
</ag-grid-angular>
```

#### EDIT2

everytime I refresh on angular app, nodejs backend is successfully poll results
[image]

I don't really understand why is not working.

#### EDIT3

I've changed the server part with this code:

```
// Retrieve all users 
app.get('/users', function (req, res) {
    dbConn.query('SELECT id,photo_date FROM p_fb_photo_search limit 10', function (error, results, fields) {

        if(error){
            res.send(JSON.stringify({"status": 500, "error": error, "response": null})); 
            //If there is error, we send the error in the error section with 500 status
        } else {
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            res.end(JSON.stringify(results, null, 3));
            //res.send(JSON.stringify(results));
            //If there is no error, all is good and response is 200OK.
        }

    });
});
```

Now I have a proper JSON as output:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Read about Observables in Angular ... async responses.

Comment: I did follow this template: https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-getting-started/, I don't understand why it works with a different JSON data set. Why should I look to async? thx

Answer (score 1):

`http.get` will return you an observable instead of your actual array of items.

Therefore, to actually display your records in the ag-grid, you'll need to either subscribe to the `http.get` call to actually get the data, or better yet, specify that `rowData` is async in your html like so:

```
<ag-grid-angular [rowData]="rowData | async"></ag-grid-angular>
```

Comment: I did change as above, but same resoult: unable to load data

Comment: I'd say the problem is definately to do with your retrieval of data. Take a look at [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yffihc) StackBlitz of your example and see if you can re-create your issue. Try adding `this.rowData.subscribe(x => console.log(x));` to your `ngOnInit` method to see exactly what the returned data is.

Comment: hello, I've added this.rowData.subscribe(x => console.log(x)); but it does not show any output. Pls see EDIT 2 above

Comment: even after change the server output, I'm still unable to see the Ag-Grid. I don't really understand how it's possible...

Comment: I've taken a look, but I don't what the problem is. I can't look at this any further without a reproducable example. :(